# asp.net 4 web forms: easiest way to display object read from a file?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

In my ASP.NET4 app, I'm reading in data from a file.  The data represents Personnel information.   The code transforms the data into Person objects with Name, Age and ID properties.  Given a list of these Person objects (let's say in an ArrayList),  can someone outline how to use one of the ASP.NET data bound objects (like Repeater, DataList, etc) to display the Person objects in formatted way?  Feel free to propose simpler alternatives than the data bound controls.  Yes, I could simply iterate thru the ArrayList of Persons and print the properties but I was looking for an automatic way to do this.  Imagine if Person had 10 properties I wanted to display.  If I can avoid it,  I rather not hardcode the property names.  Ideally I'm looking for a solution where I hand the ArrayList to some object and it magically displays the data from the Person object's simple public properties.

Comment: Josh's solution will get you there automatically, but eventually you'll want to do stuff like control the order in which fields appear, add styles to some of them, etc so you'll end up defining the columns yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a DataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"/>
```

In code-behind:

```
List<Person> people = ...;

grid.DataSource = people;
grid.DataBind();
```